# Is there an alternative to parse_makefile() in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, distutils

On `python2.7.2` we use

```
from distutils.sysconfig import parse_makefile, get_makefile_filename
make_vars=parse_makefile(get_makefile_filename())
print(make_vars["SO"])
```

`python2.7.2` Makefile:

```
# Symbols used for using shared libraries
SO=     .so
```

Now in `python3.4.2` the same code returns a wrong dictionary.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-53da0e8542b3> in <module>()
----> 1 print(make_vars["SO"])
KeyError: 'SO'
```

`python3.4.2` Makefile:

```
# Symbols used for using shared libraries
SHLIB_SUFFIX=   .so
EXT_SUFFIX= .so
```

Do you know any alternative?

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: The dictionaries you get with `python2` and `python3` don't match

Comment: Do you mean any particular value in the dictionary? It seems reasonable that certain things will be different between 2 and 3.

Comment: Please show us examples of the makefile and of the dictionaries as parsed by both 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: So far I'm changing the key manually from `["SO"]` to `["EXT_SUFFIX"]`